# Is it possible to run springboot app on port 8081 but use port 8080 as url?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I plan to run my app on port 8081 since port 8080 is used by a separate local tomcat server but users are more concerned about not changing the URL that they are used to. that url includes port 8080  since the legacy app runs on the local tomcat server. Now, would it be possible to connect the new app to port 8081 but just on the url it would still be port 8080?

Comment: if it runs on port 8081, you need to point to that port, not to port 8080

Comment: If I understood correctly, you need to run on port 8081 in your local machine since port 8080 is occupied by another tomcat, however when you deploy the app on the "public" server you don't want users to change the port in the URL and still use 8080? Is this the case?

Comment: @pleft yes that's right . users does not want to change anything on their url including port number.

Answer (score 1):

You need some kind of Proxy for this.

Every Port on your computer can be listened to by **one** application. Though you need an application that occupies this port and then forwards the request to some other application / port.

This can be done using for example Apache Webserver or Nginx. Or you can write a simple Spring Boot application that does the job: Run (and listen) at port 8080, and then use `@Controller` logic (or a `Filter`) to either forward the requests to port 8081 or to the Tomcat port.

Comment: Hi @Benjamin Thank you for sharing this. I will try this one.